# How to include all 3rdparty runtime dependencies into cmake/cpack-generated package on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, packaging, cpack

I have a c++ project with a couple of executables set up with cmake. The usual workflow is to install all 3rdparty dependencies via package manager, build and install a package via cpack on that same machine. Now, I would like to include all runtime dependencies in that package to be able to install it on another machine without needing to install 3rdparty dependencies there like on the build machine.

I did lot's of research on the web - without much success. I found something called BundleUtilities for cmake but couldn't find any entry-friendly documentation about it. I don't even know if it does what I need.

I would like to use cmake's benefits and generate such a "bundled" package without any manual intervention or anything. I do not want to assemble and copy 3rdparty dependencies manually. Ideal would be a clean cmake/cpack solution for the problem.

Edit:

To clarify: The target machine in question has no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you want to do this?  It probably won't turn out to be a great idea... packaging third party tools is effectively assuming responsibility for third party software, and as the upstream version inevitably gets out ahead of what people are finding in your tarballs that can become a real headache.  Consider whether you're really ok with seeing version conflicts because your dependencies are installed.

Why not just have cmake call out to the system's package manager at config time?  The exec_process() command will run console commands for you.